# Replace the third element of all sublists with another list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list of lists and I want to replace/update the third element of all the sublists with a new list.

```
lst1 = [['a','b','c', 3],['d','e','f', 9],['g','h','i', 'j']]            
lst2 = [2, 3, 4]
```

Desired output:

```
lst_new = [['a','b', 2, 3],['d','e', 3, 9],['g','h', 4, 'j']]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Start with `zip()` to loop over the two lists in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst1 = [['a','b','c', 3],['d','e','f', 9],['g','h','i', 'j']]            
lst2 = [2, 3, 4]

for x,y in zip(lst1,lst2): #loops over both lst1 and lst2
    x[2] = y
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 2, 3], ['d', 'e', 3, 9], ['g', 'h', 4, 'j']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `numpy`? As simple as:

```
arr1 = np.array(lst1)                                                                 
arr1[:, 2] = lst2
```

Output:

```
array([['a', 'b', '2', '3'],
       ['d', 'e', '3', '9'],
       ['g', 'h', '4', 'j']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1 = [['a','b','c', 3],['d','e','f', 9],['g','h','i', 'j']] 
lst2 = [2,3,4]

#We make a copy so that this 'lst_new' variable does not point to lst1
lst_new = lst1.copy()


for num, lst in zip(lst2, lst_new):
    lst[2] = num
#At this point, your lst_new will be changed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 3], ['d', 'e', 'f', 9], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
lst2 = [2, 3, 4]

for x in range(0, len(lst2)):
    lst1[x][2] = lst2[x]

print(lst1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of having another option:

```
map(lambda e, subls: [*subls[:2], e, *subls[3:]], lst2, lst1))
```

It makes use of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and the unpacking operator [`*`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).